# How do I use .animation(Animation.spring(), value: ????) when i dont have a value?

Tags: swiftui

Im currently using .animation(.spring()) which gives me the depreciated warning. I have managed to eliminate the warning elsewhere in the code where i have a value but in this instance i have a view with the animation that has no change of value.

Heres my code.

```
var mockupView: some View {
        Group {
            MockupPreview(
                iPhoneSettings: iPhoneSettings,
                rearIphoneSettings: rearIphoneSettings,
                overlaySettings: overlaySettings,
                iBackground: currentVisibleMockUpIndex,
                importedIBackground: importedBackground,
                importedLogo: $importedOverlay,
                opacityVignette: opacityVignette,
                backgroundHue: backgroundHue,
                backgroundSaturation: backgroundSaturation,
                backgroundBlur: backgroundBlur,
                backgroundBlurAmmount: backgroundBlurAmmount,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                bgColor: bgColor,
                screenshotImage: screenshotImage,
                importedBackgroundImage: importedBackgroundImage,
                gridVisible: gridVisible,
                accentColor: accentColor
            )
            .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth)
            .padding(.bottom)
            .animation(.spring()) // How do i replace this animation with one that animates when the view changes?
```

Comment: We can't test your code to see what is the desired effect. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help you get a good answer.

Comment: My approach would be creating a variable (e.g. a bool) and change that value when the View appears with the `.onAppear(perform:)`.